# Is the universe closed or flat?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, curvature

Apparently there is a tension in the measuring of the curvature of the universe (https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.07475) as apparently in 2018 the Planck collaboration got a series of results consistent with a closed universe (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-019-0906-9, https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09139)

But then it seems that the results were revised and found to be consistent with a flat universe (https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06892, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe section of Curvature)

Therefore, what is happening here? Has this been clarified? Is the data favouring a flat or a closed universe?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe): “Current observational evidence (WMAP, BOOMERanG, and Planck for example) imply that the observable universe is flat to within a 0.4% margin of error of the curvature density parameter with an unknown global topology.”

Comment: possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659739/